# I got the error "ErrorReauthorizeFailedReasonSessionClosed" with iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, publish-actions

I use facebook sdk on my iOS app to sign-in and sharing story.

Sharing story on Facebook feature was working properly but today it's not working. I don't know why it's not working because no code changes related to that feature.

The followings are the code that requests publish_actions permission.

```
// Request publish_actions
[FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
    defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
            // Permission not granted, tell the user we will not publish
            } else {
            // Permission granted
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"DEBUG: error = %@", error);
            // There was an error, handle it
            // See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
        }
}];
```

The error message is as followings,

```html
Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. com.facebook.sdk:ErrorReauthorizeFailedReasonSessionClosed"
UserInfo=0xXXXXXXXXX {
    com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=
        com.facebook.sdk:ErrorReauthorizeFailedReasonSessionClosed, 
    NSLocalizedFailureReason=
        com.facebook.sdk:ErrorReauthorizeFailedReasonSessionClosed, 
       com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey= ... >
}
```

If anybody knows this, please help me.

** Facebook SDK version is 3.18, and publish_actions item is already approved in developer.facebook.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **FBSDKAccessToken**

```
 if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {

            [self doShare];
        } else {
            FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
            [login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    // Process error
                } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                    // Handle cancellations
                } else {
                    // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                    // should check if specific permissions missing
                    if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"]) {
                        // Do work

                        [self doShare];

                    }
                }
            }];
        }
```

where **doShare**

-(void) doShare{

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/locations/%d",1];
NSDictionary *properties = @{

                             @"your action" :url
                             };
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
  initWithGraphPath:@"me/example-staging:something"
  parameters: properties
  HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         // NSLog(@"Post id:%@", result[@"id"]);

     }
 }];
```

Comment: is FBSDKAccessToken Facebook SDK 4.x version? Mine is 3.18.

Comment: yeah it is 4.x :) and u should use it is more easier

Comment: @MasterHong did u solve your problem or what ? let me know if u still need any help ?

Comment: I found that I already had the publish permission but "requestNewPublishPermissions" method told publish permission not granted. So I just ignored it and just uploaded story then it worked. Thank you for your replying @Omarj